# how to store information using array list

Tags: java

[**This my code, I just print screen it because I'm getting an error while posting this code**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fD5co.png)

[image]

how to make this program to store personal information and store another person information.

Comment: What error do you get when including the code? Just paste it into the question, select it all, and click on the brace icon to format it.

Comment: Given that your username is *student* and the name of your eclipse workspace is *finalproject*, I think it's safe to assume this is a homework assignment.  [This is not a good question for Stack Overflow.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: It doesn't look like there's an error per se; the only thing I see is that you call `info.get(0)` every time so will always print the first entries name. You could change it to `info.get(info.size() - 2)` and `-1` for surname if you *had* to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a do-while, then you could write a separate method for it and call it when needed

```
public void gatherUserInformation()
{
    System.out.println("Enter name:");
    ...
    System.out.println("Enter last name ");
    ...
}
```

Then call this method from your main method, and then make the first person print out.

Then in your main method, make this right after:

```
if(scan.nextInt() == 1)
{
  gatherUserInformation()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create Person class like:

```
public class Person{
    private String name;
    private String lastname;

    // void cons

    public String getName(){
       return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
       this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLastname(){
       return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname){
       this.lastname= lastname;
    }

}
```

And after that you change our main to work with that:

```
ArrayList<Person> pList = new ArrayList<>();
```

At the beginning of each loop:

```
Person person = new Person(); // void cons
```

And after that you can add 'person' in pList, use get methods to get object values and set methods to change that values:

```
person.setName(scan.next());
```

To show person name:

```
person.getName();
```

To show pList, open another loop:

```
int i = 1;
for ( Person p : pList ){
   System.out.println("Person " + i + " name: " + p.getName());
   System.out.println("Person " + i + " lastname: " + p.getLastname());
   System.out,println(" ----------------------------------------- ");
   i++; 
}
```

I do not test but I think that's it

Good Lucky